# Second element on selenium chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests

When trying to automate our application, there are two div with same parameters.

I'm not able to find a way to recognize these. Please let me know what could be the other ways to identify these elements in selenium chromedriver in python.

I tried it, no it's doesn't work for me.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='c3'])[2]/p").send_keys('text')
```

This is my html code

```
<div class="c3">
    <p> test1 </p>
</div>
<div class="c3">
    <p> test2 </p>
</div>
<div class="c3">
    <p> test3 </p>
</div>
```

I want add my text after test2

Comment: Could you share the html including container details for these two divs?

Comment: ((//div[@class='c3'])[2]/p)[1] you can use this on basis of index you can locate that element

Comment: Can you share the HTML code of these two divs to get better and optimize result?

Comment: @narine Please share the HTML so that we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the extra **parentheses()** / **parentheses at wrong place** in your xpath.

Correct xpath would be:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='c3'][2]/p").send_keys('text')
```

**OR**

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='c3']/p)[2]").send_keys('text')
```